# How to link Firestore collections to simulate SQL joins or WHERE IN

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I have a Firebase Cloud Firestore database with 3 collections; Sites, Groups and GroupSites. Groups can be associated with many sites, hence the GroupSites collection. If  have a Group ID, I want to retrieve associated sites via their GroupSites membership. Data looks like this:

```
Sites:
   - Id: ByBWwnFVXqnJO8FL5n2y
     - SiteName: Penrith
     - Supervisor: Bob
     - Address: zzz site address
   - Id: Hfui74ytBBzUw3OjIg1f
     - SiteName: Keswick
     - Supervisor: Bill
     - Address: yyy site address
   - Id: KKeQen0P3npldFVzt7fG
     - SiteName: Browns Plains
     - Supervisor: Tony
     - Address: xxx site address
Groups:
   - Id: iAX0GE9ZRU0AuxXMBkid
     - GroupName: Group 1
     - isPublic: 0
GroupSites:
   - Id: jxpvUYkopOXNhKisYznC
     - siteId: ByBWwnFVXqnJO8FL5n2y
     - groupId: iAX0GE9ZRU0AuxXMBkid
   - Id: p0jq3clihb0JRjhH5qon
     - siteId: Hfui74ytBBzUw3OjIg1f
     - groupId: iAX0GE9ZRU0AuxXMBkid
```

So, for instance, if I had the Group Id of 'iAX0GE9ZRU0AuxXMBkid', I would want to retrieve Sites 'Penrith' and 'Keswick'
In SQL I could easily perform something like:

```
SELECT [SiteName], [Supervisor] 
FROM Sites 
WHERE Id IN (
   SELECT [siteId] 
   FROM [GroupSites] 
   WHERE groupId = 'iAX0GE9ZRU0AuxXMBkid'
)
```

...or I could perform a SELECT FROM Sites, joined on [GroupSites].
My problem is replicating this in Firebase. I can select from the GroupSites table with my GroupId criteria, but what to do with the returned results to then query the Sites table?

All of the examples I'm finding online seem to refer to earlier versions of the firebase - or perhaps because I'm using the AngularFirestoreCollection library they don't relate, because I have syntax or 'method not found' errors on practically everything I come across.

Here's my angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface GroupSite {
  id?: string;
  groupId: string;
  siteId: string;
}

export interface Site {
  id?: string;
  siteName: string;
  supervisor: string;
  address: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SiteService {
  private sitesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Site>; 
  private sites: Observable<Site[]>;

  private groupSitesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<GroupSite>;
  private groupSites: Observable<GroupSite[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.sitesCollection = db.collection<Site>('Site');

    this.sites = this.sitesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  } 

  getSites() {
    return this.sites;
  }

  getSitesByGroup(groupId: string) {

    this.groupSitesCollection = this.db.collection<GroupSite>('GroupSites'), ref => ref.where('groupId', '==', groupId);
    this.groupSites = this.groupSitesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };  
        });
      })
    ); 

    console.log('groupSites: ', this.groupSites)

    // get Sites referenced in this.groupSites

    return this.sites;
  }
}
```

the console.log() statement in my code returns an empty object and I understand that it's because the data hasn't returned yet from firebase, so I suspect that to get [Sites] it will need to be within snapshotChanges().pipe(), but I can't find any example to work.

Answer (score 1):

A single query cannot effectively involve documents in two different collections.  For your schema, since you are involving documents in two collections, you will need to perform multiple queries to be able to read everything required.

You'll have to take the results of the groupSitesCollection query, iterate the resulting documents to get all the siteId fields, and perform new queries to get each siteId document from the Sites collection.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too, but that's what I'm struggling with on two fronts. 1) where in my existing code do in initiate the forEach query, and 2) how do I push forEach results into my sites<SITE[]> observable?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore collections allow sub-collections, you could duplicate data inside a collection (if needed) with a firestore function if you need to update automatically, for example the name and id.

You could save a dynamic collection that resembles your query, just need to define the logic on every event related to the schema.

- catalogs

  - sites [name, id, supervisor, address, groupId]
  - groups [name, id]
- relCatalogs (this you use for your "join" queries)

  - groups/{groupId}/sites [id, name]
- functions

  - onCreate/update Site -> set id and name in relCatalog